# How can I get unix times for the start and end of last twelve months in a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, time

I wish to print the totals of a column in my database for each month in the last year. The code I have so far to do this is:

```
$month = date("n");
$year  = date("Y");

$loop = 12;
while($loop>1) {
    $first = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
    $last = mktime(23,59,00,$month+1,0,$year);

    $spendingData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spending WHERE date BETWEEN $first AND $last") or die(mysql_error());
    $totalMonth = 0;
    while($spending = mysql_fetch_array($spendingData))
    {
        $totalMonth = $totalMonth + $spending['amount'];
    }
    print "&pound;".$totalMonth;
    $loop = $loop-1;
    print "<br>";
}
```

My quesiton is how, in the loop, do I adjust the times for each month? I thought about just taking a months worth of seconds away from the timestamps, but as I don't know how many days are in each month I don't think this will work. I also don't think I can just keep taking 1 away from the month figure as this will not account for years. I also don't want to hard code the figures in, as they will change with each new month.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this rather trivially in MySQL:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM yourtable
WHERE YEAR(date) = $year
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

without ever having to involve PHP for the date manipulation stuff.

Comment: Thank you. Will this still work if the date field is a unix timestamp?

Comment: not directly, but you can convert the timestamp to a date value with `from_unixtime()`.

Comment: Sorry, what date value? Isn't that PHP? How does this tie into the SQL query?

Comment: `MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))`